# Java Logic confusion

Tags: java, reference

Can someone explain to me why with this code prints out "abeb" instead of abcb? I understood it was because you reference list2 from list1 so changing list2 also changes list1 but I'm not quite understanding that entirely.

```
char [] list1 = {'a','b','c','d'};    
char [] list2 = list1;    
list2[2] = 'e';    
list1[3] = list2[1]    
for (char a: list1)    
out.print(a)`
```

Why is the same logic(the logic I'm understanding) not being applied here in this code?
It prints out x as "5" were from what I understood from the code above it should be 7?

```
int x = 5;
int y = x;
y += 2;
out.print(x);
```

Comment: You aren't mutating anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`list2[2] = 'e'` assigns a new value, 'e', to the third element of the `list2` array. It thus modifies the array. `list2` and `list1` are two variables containing a reference to the same array.

Before:

```
list1 --> [a, b, c, d]
          ^
          |
list2 ---/
```

After:

```
list1 --> [a, b, e, d]
          ^
          |
list2 ---/
```

`y += 2` increments the value of the variable `y`, which is different from the value of the variable `x`:

Before:

```
x  --> 5
y  --> 5
```

After:

```
x --> 5
y --> 7
```

Comment: I was drawing the same image :_(

Comment: So it's only because list1 and list2 are objects that this happens? And since ints aren't objects, they're just treated individually?

Comment: Yes. list1 and list2 point to the same object, and you're modifying the content of this object. x and y point to different primitive values and you're modifying one of the values. If you did `list2 = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'e', 'd'}`, then you would also modify the value of list2, as you did in the second example, and list1 would still reference the original array.

Answer (score 2):

This is because, first operation you are doing is on **arrays** and they are treated as **objects** in Java.

But second operation is done on **`int`** and that is a primitive type. So **reference** rule doesn't apply here.